# jQuery - after()-function fires twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-after

This is my code snippet:

```
$.ctrl('J', function() {

    $("#"+currentId).after('<div contentEditable="true">test</div>'); 

});
```

After running it, 2 divs with "test" will be added instead of 1.

What am I missing?

This is the CTRL function:

```
$.ctrl = function(key, callback, args) {

    var isCtrl = false;

    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (!args) args = [];
        if (e.ctrlKey) isCtrl = true;
        if (e.keyCode == key.charCodeAt(0) && isCtrl) {
            callback.apply(this, args);
            return false;
        }
    }).keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey) isCtrl = false;
    });
};
```

Thank you in advance.

Greetings

Edit:

maybe it has something to do with this:

```
$('div[id|="edid"]').focus(function() {


       $('div[id|="edid"]').removeClass('onFocus'); 

       $(this).addClass('onFocus'); 

       var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Comment: It seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/6RPhs/.

Comment: Make sure you aren't calling `$.ctrl` twice.  That might elicit the behavior you are describing.

Comment: That's strange. Maybe it has something to to with the $("#"+currentId). I am editing it in my origin posting.

Comment: Do you have more than one item sharing the same ID?

Comment: Hi David. Not that I know of. See my Editing above. My Test html page contains of 3 div-tags, having different IDs. (edid-0-1, edid-0-2 and edid-0-3). The function edited above ensures, that events only happen to the chosen tag, and not to all beginning with "edid". So far, it worked fine. Until this double firing with .after()...

Comment: Are you holding it down? Maybe try using `.keyup()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem. May be you are using an old jquery version?

> Major Bugfix in JQuery 1.4.4
>   - A function bound to the document ready event will now fire once (it
>   was firing twice).

[What’s New in JQuery 1.4.4](http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-144-whats-new/)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably including jQuery two times in your HTML code. Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
```